# Animation not working

Tags: android, animation

```
Intent intent = null;
intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);          
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.slide_down_out);  
ClassSelector.this.finish();            
startActivity(intent);
```

I need to have a transition from current page to another page that is A. i have added code 'intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);'
since this code is applied animation that is applied for A is nor working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the two flags

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

have opposite intention. One brings the old activity on top and the other creates a new task
which could have results that cannot be predicted.

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

which could bring the animation you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `finish()` in your activity, right after you call `startActivity()` (and get rid of your flags), and then in the new activity, in its `onBackPressed()` method, to call this code:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the overridePendingTransition call after startActivity.

Ex:

```
    Intent intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    ClassSelector.this.finish();            
    startActivity(intent);          
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.slide_down_out);
```